# Razor Syntax in External Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So as you might know, Razor Syntax in ASP.NET MVC does not work in external JavaScript files.

My current solution is to put the Razor Syntax in a  a global variable and set the value of that variable from the mvc view that is making use of that .js file.

**JavaScript file:**

```
function myFunc() {
  alert(myValue);
}
```

**MVC View file:**

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    myValue = @myValueFromModel;
</script>
```

I want to know how I can  pass myValue ***directly as a parameter*** to the function ? I prefer to have explicit calling with param than relying on globals, however I'm not so keen on javascript.

How would I implement this with javascript parameters? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have your function accept an argument and use that in the alert (or wherever).

external.js

```
function myFunc(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

someview.cshtml

```
<script>
    myFunc(@myValueFromModel);
</script>
```

One thing to keep in mind though, is that if `myValueFromModel` is a string then it is going to come through as `myFunc(hello)` so you need to wrap that in quotes so it becomes `myFunc('hello')` like this

```
myFunc('@(myValueFromModel)');
```

Note the extra `()` used with razor. This helps the engine distinguish where the break between the razor code is so nothing odd happens. It can be useful when there are nested `(` or `"` around.

*edit*

If this is going to be done multiple times, then some changes may need to take place in the JavaScript end of things. Mainly that the shown example doesn't properly depict the scenario. It will need to be modified. You may want to use a simple structure like this.

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ugdk2ctq/)***

external.js

```
var myFunc= new function(){
 var func = this,
 myFunc = function(){
    alert(func.value);
 };
 myFunc.set = function(value){
    func.value = value;
 }
 return myFunc;
};
```

someview.cshtml

```
<script>
    myFunc.set('@(myValueFromModel)');
    myFunc();//can be called repeatedly now
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks great. Would I have to pass in that parameter every time the function is called? I call that function like 30 times throughout the cshtml so would I have to change all those calls or is there a different way?

Comment: @TalalNabulsi - In that case you are probably going to want to store the variable. It is possible to store it once inside of an object as opposed to using a global variable to protect the state. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit Travis! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I often find that JavaScript in the browser is typically conceptually tied to a specific element. If that's the case for you, you may want to associate the value with that element in your Razor code, and then use JavaScript to extract that value and use it in some way.

For example:

```
<div class="my-class" data-func-arg="@myValueFromModel"></div>
```

Static JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.my-class').click(function() {
         var arg = $(this).data('func-arg');
         myFunc(arg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to execute your function immediately? Or want to call the funcion with the parameter?

You could add a wrapper function with no parameter and inside call your function with the global var as a parameter. And when you need to call myFunc() you call it trough myFuncWrapper();

```
function myFuncWrapper(){ 
    myFunc(myValue);
}

function myFunc(myParam){
//function code here;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I'm looking for. I have to put the wrapper function in the cshtml view correct?

Comment: As far as you define your var myValue in your cshtml you will be able to access that variable on your external js file... so you could put both functions on the jsfile and only the variable declaration/assignment on cshtml